# Формат auto increment столбца

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать небольшой хеплдеск. Интересует вот что: как сделать автовставку `ID` типа 000000000001, 00000000002, 00000000003, etc... а не как обычно 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно на уровне дб ничего не изменять, а билдить такие ид с помощью [str_pad](http://md.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$id = str_pad($id, 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого в MySQL было введено характеристику поля `zerofill`

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`blabla` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL 
);
```

Почему это лучше сделать в MySQL, а не PHP? Потому, что меняя размер поля `id` вам, придется также изменить размер и в коде. Не говоря уже о дополнительной операции вместо стандартной функции.